# Iterate through all possible bytes

Tags: go, byte

So I'm trying to test a function against every possible **byte**, that is `0` to `255` possibilities. How do I iterate over all possible bytes? i've

I've tried

```
 for i := 0; i < 256; i++ {
      fmt.Println(byte(i)) // prints a number 0-255
      fmt.Println(byte{i}) // crashes
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean _doesn't work_?

Comment: It's still unclear to me what's wrong with `byte(i)`.

Comment: I need to wrap it in `string()`. I was unaware that the numbers I was printing were in fact bytes... because, well, bytes are just numbers

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you need to ensure that "i" variable is a byte (i.e. uint8), then you can do:

```
for i := byte(0); i < 255; i++ {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't loop over `byte(255)`.

Comment: Unfortunately flipping the condition to i < 256 doesn't work - it causes a type error, since 256 isn't a valid `byte`, and if you try to do `int(i) < 256`, you end up in an infinite loop because of overflow. I don't think there's an elegant way to code this up, unfortunately, short of actually using a `make([]byte, 256)`.

Comment: @Pockets I took a stab at a way to avoid the infinite loop, please see my answer. I will let you decide if it is elegant. It doesn't introduce any extra helper ints, instead it works directly on a single incremented byte. The trick is to explicitly state when the byte should be incremented, and when to break out of the loop. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A tricky part about looping over uint8(aka 'byte') values is that adding 1 to 255 takes you back to zero. It is easy to accidentally form an infinite loop if your for-loop condition is `i <= 255`. If the goal is to iterate over every possible byte, [0-255], without introducing an indexer of a larger type, you can do it, but must be careful.

A for loop in go has three optional parts. It's a template or shorthand for manually specifying initialization, break condition and increment/decrements. (I use these names loosely b/c you can execute whatever kind of statements/expressions you want, or none at all)

I am going to write some broken code that loops forever, then rewrite it in a more explicit way:

original broken:

```
for i := byte(0); i <= 255; i++ {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

is similar to this explicit broken version:

```
i := byte(0)

for ; ;  {
    if i <= 255{
        fmt.Println(i)
        i++
    } else { 
        break
    }
}
```

Looking at the second example, we can more easily see the problem. We want to break out of the loop when `i==255`, but only after running `fmt.Println(i)` -- and we definitely *don't* want to increment when `i == 255`. There is nothing sacred about the order in which for loops check conditions and increment -- if the default order is not suited for our case, rewrite the code explicitly in an order that works. In our case, we are mostly concerned with when to break out of the loop:

a properly functioning example:

```
i := byte(0)

for ; ; {
    fmt.Println(i)
    if i == 255{
        break
    } else { 
        i++
    }
}
```

A more concise functioning example:

```
for i := byte(0); ;i++ {
    fmt.Println(i)
    if i == 255{
        break
    }
}
```

While we are here, I will point out that for loops are abstractions surrounding conditional jump statements, or in otherwords -- gotos. In this case, I think there might be some instructional value in seeing how it would work with an explicit jump/goto:

```
i := byte(0)

printI:
fmt.Println(i)

if i < 255 {
    i++
    goto printI
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you'd like to preserve the traditional for-loop syntax for readability --

```
for i := 0; i < 256; i++ {
    fmt.Println(byte(i))
}
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/jjjg9YgXSjc

Answer (score -2):

To me it looks like `fmt.Println(byte(i))` is working. What output were you expecting?